# What does a dot inside two parenthesis mean on a weather depiction chart?

Tags: weather, symbology

Earlier today, a friend asked me what this symbol (referring to an airport in Canada) on a weather depiction chart represented.  I didn't know. (Full chart available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzB5y.png))

[image: Dot inside parenthesis on a weather depiction chart]

**What does a dot inside parenthesis mean on a weather depiction chart?**

Comment: What agency produced the chart?

Comment: @Articuno - The [Aviation Weather Center](https://aviationweather.gov/iffdp/misc).  I've edited in a link to the full chart.

Comment: Looks like its a NOAA chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://www.msrc.sunysb.edu/~chang/atm247/Ch2_figures/weather_symbols_2.jpg), $(\cdot)$ means that there is precipitation within sight, reaching the ground, not at the station, but < 5 km from the station.

$)\cdot($ means that there is precipitation within sight, reaching the ground, not at the station, but > 5km from the station.

[This source](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/weatherstation/technical/symbols/symbol.html) and [this source](http://www.atmo.arizona.edu/students/courselinks/spring12/atmo170a1s2/lecture_notes/station_model/sta_model_handout_p01.jpg) give similar definitions, but without a strict distance cutoff, instead just saying "distant" and "near".

I couldn't find any references to this symbol in [Nav Canada's weather code and symbol legend](https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/CreePage.pl?Langue=anglais&NoSession=NS_Inconnu&Page=wxsymbols&TypeDoc=wxsymb).